# why does tar -cf ${PWD}.bz2 not produce any output?

Tags: linux, bash

I ran the following command.  `tar -jcvf ${PWD}.bz2 a b c d`.  I expected a bz2 folder as the output. But the command did not output anything. what am i missing ?

Comment: Any title referencing "this Linux command" is uselessly vague: It doesn't help anyone tell if they can help you with your question (or if your question's answers will help them) without following the link to see what "this command" is. Try to build titles descriptive enough to fulfil that goal.

Comment: BTW, I'd suggest `"${PWD##*/}.bz2"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your command syntax is correct, so if you have permissions for reading a,b,c,d file (or directory???) and write to ./.. directory (one level up), file should be created.

example command output (a,b,d - files, c - directory with 2 files)

```
a
b
c/
c/file2
c/file1
d
```

at the end just type:

```
stat ${PWD}.bz2
```

Regards,

Comment: Why does it create in a parent directory instead of the same directory ?

Comment: Inside path: `/a/b/c/d` `${PWD}.bz2` mean: `/a/b/c/d.bz2`.
If your intention is file `/a/b/c/d/d.bz2` try this: `${PWD}/$(basename ${PWD}).bz `

Answer (score 0):

When you want a output file in a bz2 dir, use `${PWD}/bz2/outputfile`